# Mysql left join with nested select slow, how to optimize

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a LEFT JOIN mysql query which is very slow to excecute and I'm looking for a inprovment.
I have a table 'VM' that list the 'VmId' (+ some other datas) and another table "VM_Status" that list the status (up/down) of a VM and each row has an 'inputDate'.

Table VM is 7.000 rows and Table VM_Status is 76.000 rows

I need to select the latest status for the 7.000 VM

My query is the following and take 25 sec to execute :

```
SELECT 
VM.*,
`VM_Status`.`Status` AS `Status`
FROM VM
left join (
   select
       * 
   from
       `VM_Status` `s1`
   where
       (
           `s1`.`InputDate` = (
               select
                   max(`s2`.`InputDate`)
               from
                   `VM_Status` `s2`
               where
                   (`s1`.`VmId` = `s2`.`VmId`)
           )
       )

) `VM_Status` on(
   (
       `VM_Status`.`VmId` = `WORKLOAD`.`VmId`
   )
)
```

How can I do the same quicker ?

Comment: See the added Tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions.
[Window Functions in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html)

MySQL supports window functions that, for each row from a query, perform a calculation using rows related to that row.

In your case you can use the RANK() or DENSE_RANK() functions with an order by clause and get that MAX inside the window (avoiding the slow join).
See: [RANK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank)

Something similar to this:

```
select 
    *
from (
SELECT 
    VM.*,
    `VM_Status`.`Status` AS `Status`,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY `VM_Status`.`VmId` ORDER BY `VM_Status`.`InputDate` DESC) rank
    FROM VM left join `VM_Status`
    ON `VM_Status`.`VmId` = `VM`.`VmId`
) `last_status`
WHERE 
    rank = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know RANK(). But I'm on version 5.7 and I thing RANK() is available only on 8. I tried an aleternative but it return me 78.000 row from rank 1 to rank 78.000... What I have missed ?

select 
    *
from (
 SELECT 
  VM.VmId,
  VM_Status.`Status` AS `Status`,
  @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Rank
  FROM (SELECT @curRank := 0) r, VM left join VM_Status ON VM_Status.VmId = VM.VmId
  ORDER BY VM_Status.InputDate DESC
  ) `last_status`
 ORDER BY Rank